# AS3 stage.Activate and stage.deactivate works for user click on the iPad home button?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I would like to detect the user tap the home button the quit the app, and come back to the app . is stage.activate and stage.deactivate works?

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE,volRestore);
stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE,volFade);
```

Cheers
Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are the correct Events to listen for - on mobile, the app wont actually exit, it will just 'freeze' when user 'closes' it.

Not sure if you need to attach to Stage though - "this" should suffice - assuming your code is in top level of app.

Comment: Sweet thanks, I will try them now. this.addEventListner isntead